# Should a web developer use a Content Management System Software?

Tags: web-applications, content-management-system

First of all, I want to say that I can't find any satisfactory/reasonable answer to this question anywhere else. So, I thought I would ask it here. Sorry if this question is too vague to fit in here; I will try to be more specific.

Here are my questions.

**1) Who are encouraged to use a Content Management System?**

Are only non-technical persons who are not interested in learning programming/web-designing, or even programmers/developers are encouraged to solely depend on a CMS?

**2) Does using a CMS limit our understanding?**

I've heard people saying that `CMS`s limit us from understanding the inner functionalities of the working of the web server and security issues. For example, is it as straightforward as making a small change in the server's configuration file and restarting the server?

**3) Don't we have more control on our website while using a CMS?**

Control, in the sense of adding our own extra modules and different methods of doing a specific task (like processing a request) in a slightly advantageous way. For example, I heard a friend of mine saying that, it is much complicated with bring in our hard-coded design (using CSS) because affecting one slight design made unexpected changes in different pages.

**4) How about using CMS for a web-based product/service?**

As in a professional web application which expects more users and assuming that all the members of the development team are OK with hard coding.
[Edit] There is a difference between a blogging website and a social networking site. In this context, I consider the social networking site more of a web-based service rather than a blogging website (which mostly is a personal website).

Someone also mentioned that, `CMS`s consume more resources. Is that true?

**5) What would you suggest for a web designer/developer?**

Your advice for a web developer who cares much about quality, scalability and security than trying to do things with ease.

Comment: Answers for 1-5: "It depends."

Comment: @ceejayoz depends on what? I think you didn't read the description under each question. I've tried to be as specific as possible.

Comment: Depends on all sorts of things. The task at hand, the developer's skills and internal motivations, etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz The task is defined in question 4 and the developer's internal motivations are defined in question 5. Added a little bit additional description to question 4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To each of your questions.

1:Non-technical people without much programming experience, or for people who want to make general blogs/websites without much technical requirements. Yes you can create a basic website with CMS fairly quickly; but if you have any very technical back-end work (like FaceBook) it is best to actually script things instead of using a CMS.

2: In some situations. For very basic things like HTML you are not really missing out on that much understanding in functionality. But some CMS have plugins that have built-in tasks that without actually coding it your self or having enough experience to read over the source code you could not fully understand what exactly is happening and determine if it is the most efficient solution.

3: In general no, when using a CMS you are limited to what resources/plugins you can find. Of course most CMS allow you to add scripts to your website and make more personalized functionality; but compared to writing all the scripts yourself there is not as much customization.

4: You can use a CMS for a professional web application; but that again depends on your needs. If it is a application with simple technical needs then yes you can make it professional quality with only a CMS. But if it is very technical, it would probably be a better solution to actually code the application.

5: As a web-developer of 5 years experience I strongly prefer coding things myself because then I know exactly what is going on in my scripts; and my customization is only limited by my coding ability and not some platform. Of course if someone is not that programming savvy I would have to suggest using CMS because that be more reliable than having badly coded scripts created by someone who isn't very sure of what they are doing. But if they are comfortable in coding their application; I would strongly suggest that over CMS.

Answer (score 3):

**1) Who are encouraged to use a Content Management System?**

I believe that Content Management Systems are good for both technical and non-technical people. Of course, that depends on which CMS you choose. It is helpful to be a programmer, designer, or developer in many CMS products.

**2) Does using a CMS limit our understanding?**

Using a CMS doesn't mean that you don't have to understand a web server or a programming language (especially PHP). It all depends on how you host the product. For example, if you use GoDaddy's shared hosting service and you use their Hosting Connection, you don't learn the ins and outs of installing the CMS yourself or necessarily deal with patching a web server. On the other hand, if you install the CMS on your own box, you need to configure, harden, and patch the web server. Install PHP (or a different language), Install MySQL (or something similar). Generally a LAMP.

**3) Don't we have more control on our website while using a CMS?**

I wouldn't say that it is more control, I'd actually say it is less. However, if you don't have the skills to build what the CMS offers, it is better to give up some control. You should back-up a hand-coded site or a CMS so either should be able to be rolled back if something goes bad.

**4) How about using CMS for a web-based product/service?**

I think you need to clarify this even more. I don't know of a CMS that is geared toward social networking.

**5) What would you suggest for a web designer/developer?**

I'd suggest they follow the money. Skills that you develop as a web designer/developer while using a CMS transfer (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

1. Who are encouraged to use a Content Management System?

   CMSes are built to make things easier, put the best practices into action, cut down the development of what actually a repeated task and so on. So if you are developer or webmaster or any other person interested in building a website, you can consider using a CMS based on the features that the CMS provide, the API and hooks that it gives you to extend etc. However there is no hardcore rule that decides who can use them.
2. Does using a CMS limit our understanding?

   IMHO, no. you are going to learn something new. For example, if you are learning jQuery doesn't mean you are limiting your understanding on JavaScript. Most CMSes eases the tasks by providing necessary functionality but does not limit you to explore the underlying things. If  they do, you should seriously consider avoiding using such CMS. However you should also consider the fact that no software is perfect, and may contain the security issues or bugs. But it is the same case even if you code the software yourself.
3. Don't we have more control on our website while using a CMS?

   It depends on what you want to achieve.
4. How about using CMS for a web-based product/service?

   I personally prefer the CMS for web-based product/service specially the one like social networking site. However if it is an ecommerce website, I would go for coding instead of using CMS. Using CMS will ease the job of coding the things which you don't need to. For example, user management, authentication etc. However it depends on the CMS you choose. If the CMS is  powerful enough you to do complex things, it is good.
5. What would you suggest for a web designer/developer?

   > Your advice for a web developer who cares much about quality,
   >   scalability and security than trying to do things with ease.

   I would suggest an open source CMS with active community. However if you have a team of developers who can actively work and maintain, developing your own CMS will let you customize the way you want, optimize for better performance for your environment and so on.

   Security: There are two sides for it.

   1. If the CMS is open source and is developed by active community, the number of security issues will be less but any new issue found will affect your site considerably in less time.
   2. If the code is closed source, the security issues may not get caught by attackers so quickly but there are chances of more issues, if the code is not properly developed, tested etc.

So the conclusion is decide the best choice based on your requirements rather than going blindly with any of the approach.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my questions. Question 4 has been edited to provide more detailed description. Ans your answer for question 5 means, `CMS`s have the same quality/performance as hard-coded websites. However, I read that they consume more resources.

Comment: Thanks, updated my comment as well. Regarding performance, it depends on the CMS and its features. There is no guarantee that your team will develop the site with optimal performance than a CMS. A good CMS with active community can take advantage of testing by more people on more websites and is tend to get more stable.

Comment: By good `CMS`s, you mean any of the popular ones available now like Drupal, Joomla or Wordpress?

Comment: Yes. Joomla, Drupal or Wordpress are no doubt the good CMSes and have good active community, but CMSes not just limited to them. There are many, including few commercial ones. You should choose the one depend on your requirement.

Comment: That was informative. thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many different solutions to every problem. My general rule of thumb for this is if the majority of people contributing content to the website are not programmers, use a CMS. On the other hand, if the majority of people are programmers, and the content will continue to be maintained that way, then I wouldn't use one. It largely depends on your specific situation though.